# How can I set my path so that it works with Python code that is locally installed as a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am developing a set of python files that should work together as a package.  The file has the following structure.

```
    PyFinances
    ├─.venv
    ├─LICENSE
    ├─Makefile
    ├─README.rst
    ├─requirements.txt
    ├─setup.py
    ├─test
    │  ├─test_pyfinances.py
    │  └─read_files.py
    └─PyFinances
       ├─pyfinances.py
       └─read_files.py
```

The header and the first function in the `pyfinances.py` file looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from read_files import ReadRunOptionsFile

def pyfinances():
    "generic content here"
    return 25.0
```

I successfully installed the code in a virtual environment with the following two commands

```
pip3 install wheel
pip3 install .
```

Which yield the following response

```
Successfully installed PyFinances-0.1.0
```

To test the package install, I `cd` 4 or 5 directories away from where the source code is, create a file titled `test.py` with the following import statement at the top of the file

```
from PyFinances.pyfinances import pyfinances
```

The import seems to have worked because it does not tell me that it does not recognize PyFinances, but instead it does not recognize the `read_file` module and I get the error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'read_files'
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you prefix the files with _ ? It means you cannot import them using an `import` without `from`

Comment: first of all there must be an `__init__.py` under each directory

Comment: @anurag there is an __init__.py file.  I forgot to put that in my directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... You didn't import `_read_files`, you imported `pyfinance`. Here's what you probably should do:

```py
import PyFinances.pyfinances as pfy
import PyFinances.read as pfr
```

For this to work, I should note, you must remove the underscores from the beginning of your source filenames (and edit setup.py accordingly). The way you have them named would only allow for the use of a `from ... import ...`, and no `import ... as ...`

And, you're also missing `__init__.py` in every directory. It does not require any code in it, you just need it to exist in `PyFinances/`, `PyFinances/test/`, and `PyFinances/PyFinances/`.

Comment: It took me a bit to understand what you meant by underscore.  There are no _ symbols in front of the module names.  The _ is only to indicate that the file exists under the directory shown above it in the directory tree.  So the module IS read_files, not _read_files.  Also, there is an __init__.py file, I just forgot to put that in the directory tree description and will fix that in a second.  Also, why would I want to import PyFinances.read in the main file, when read is imported by pyfinances and that is all I want?

Comment: @Jon ooh, understood. I will remove that from my answer. I might also edit your question to make that a bit more clear.

Comment: @Jon If my answer worked for you, be sure to accept it. If you don't it may look to others having this issue that there is not a solved answer.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your answer.  After turning the software into a package I created a file called test.py many directories removed so it did not link to the source, but the package instead.  Are you suggesting that I import PyFinances.read as pfr in that file and if so, why?  I only want the pyfinances function, within the pyfinances module.  It is the pyfinances module that imports the read module to support the pyfinances function.

Comment: Actually, @Jon, I have no idea why this error is occuring in that case. I'll do some testing when I am back to my computer, but until then I cannot help you.

Comment: It is not rush, and I appreciate any help you can give.  I will keep experimenting on my end as well.

Comment: I may have solved the problem.  I am going to fully test it, and if it works I will answer the question.

Comment: There were several things causing the problem.  I had some specific information in my __init__.py files.  While you did not directly suggest that I remove the info, it was your response that made me decide to remove the information and leave the files blank, which seems to have fixed the problem.  Therefore I am going to credit your answer as having solved the problem.

Comment: @Jon It is good to hear that you were able to solve your problem. I hope you have a nice day!